# How to properly send stop condition when using DMA with I2C?

Tags: i2c, interrupts, stm32f4, dma

I'm using DMA transfer to get 1024 bytes from master (STM32F407VG) to slave OLED screen (SSD1306). The library I'm using does this:

```
extern void DMA1_Stream4_IRQHandler(void)
{
    // I2C3 DMA transmit completed
    if (DMA_GetFlagStatus(DMA1_Stream4, DMA_FLAG_TCIF4) != RESET)
    {
        // Stop DMA, clear interrupt
        DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Stream4, DISABLE);
        DMA_ClearFlag(DMA1_Stream4, DMA_FLAG_TCIF4);
        I2C_DMACmd(I2C3, DISABLE);
        TM_I2C_Stop(I2C3); // send i2c stop
    }
}
```

But I read that DMA usually finishes before I2C finishes transmitting last byte and if you stop it (TM_I2C_Stop(I2C3)) there the last byte is never transmitted.
So I read on StackOvf that the right way may be to use separate interrupt for I2C and send stop condition there. So I tried:

```
I2C_ITConfig(I2C3, I2C_IT_BTF, ENABLE);
I2C_ClearFlag(I2C3, I2C_FLAG_BTF);
// Set interupt controller for I2C
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = I2C3_EV_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
```

and the handler:

```
extern void I2C3_EV_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C3, I2C_FLAG_BTF) != RESET)
    {
        TM_I2C_Stop(I2C3); // send i2c stop
        I2C_ClearFlag(I2C3, I2C_FLAG_BTF);
    }
}
```

but the handler never gets called and program gets stuck because it can't send any data through I2C anymore because it says its busy. Now Im starting to think that BTF might not be the right interrupt event, although it says in documentation:

> Master transmitter: In the interrupt routine after the EOT interrupt, disable DMA requests then wait for a BTF event before programming the Stop condition.

But blocking the entire CPU in interrupt routine until I2C finishes seems a little silly, especially when there is BTF interrupt available.
What is the correct way of calling the I2C and interrupts to avoid truncating the last byte?

Comment: Its better two write a spcific question, and better to be specific in general. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could the initialization in the library be interfering with your 'manual' configuration?

Comment: Found out it was my wrong configuration of interrupts.
I found a hacky way to do it and it seems to work. I enable I2C interrupts just for that short duration between DMA TC interrupt and I2C Byte Transfer Complete interrupt (inside DMA TC interrupt with I2C_ITConfig(SSD1306_I2C, I2C_IT_EVT, ENABLE);) Then in I2Cx_EVT_IRQn I do
 if (I2C_GetITStatus(SSD1306_I2C, I2C_IT_BTF))
 {
  TM_I2C_Stop(SSD1306_I2C);      
  I2C_ITConfig(SSD1306_I2C, I2C_IT_EVT, DISABLE);
 }
and it seems to work for now. I hope there arent any unwanted side effects.

Comment: My initial mistake was using I2C_ITConfig(SSD1306_I2C, I2C_IT_BTF, ENABLE); instead of I2C_ITConfig(SSD1306_I2C, I2C_IT_EVT, ENABLE);